# AWS EMR Presto job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, presto

Is it possible to submit presto jobs/steps in any way to an EMR cluster just like you can submit Hive jobs/steps via a script in S3?

I would not like to SSH to the instance to execute the commands, but do it automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use any JDBC/ODBC client to connect with Presto cluster. You can do this with available drivers if you want to connect programmatically.

https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html
https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/0.167-t/installation/odbc.html

If you do have any BI tool like tableau, Clickview, Superset then it can be easily done as well.

e.g https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_presto.htm